# NullPointerException load fxml

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I want to load an fxml file in my application. I use the next code:

```
try {
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setController(null);
   loader.setRoot(null);
   loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE));
   Node root = null;
   root = (Node) loader.load(JfxUtils.class.getResource(fxml).openStream());
   return root;
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("cannot load FXML screen", e);
}
```

With some fxml, all work fine, with others I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.equals(FXMLLoader.java:1856)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.isCyclic(FXMLLoader.java:1868)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2100(FXMLLoader.java:71)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:570)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2356)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2172)
```

I don't understand why I get this exception.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Add include exemple:

My parent fxml

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" fx:id="scrollPane" id="scrollStocksList"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="net.StocksListRunningController">
    <fx:include fx:id="tableListStock"
        source="/fxml/stocksList.fxml" />
</fx:root>
```

My include file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="net.StockListTableController">
    <TableView fx:id="stocksList" onMouseClicked="#openDetail">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="Titre" prefWidth="125">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="title" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Quantité" prefWidth="75" fx:id="quantityColumn">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="quantity" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Prix unitaire" prefWidth="100">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="unitPrice" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Prix total" prefWidth="120">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="price" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Sens" prefWidth="50">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="direction" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Date d'achat" prefWidth="100">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="date" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Jours écoulés" prefWidth="100">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="dayRunning" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: It seems that the object `fxml` is null. Can you check it?

Comment: I check that, the fxml is not null and the path is correct.

Comment: Which version of JavaFX are you using? Try to update it to latest one.

Comment: I use thé version provided by jdk 7.0.51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Add this line for the loader:

```
loader.setLocation(JfxUtils.class.getResource(fxml));
```

Very bad bug.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for loading fxml is:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_tableview.fxml"));
```

The reason for your NullPointerException is likely due to the fact that I don't see any definition of your `fxml` variable. Also, I'm not sure about that .openStream() bit at the end of yours.

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) for more info on FXML.

***EDIT***

In light of the comments, There are..3 or so places there I see that you could be getting this NPE.

Place #1) loader is null, since we can see it's clearly not, this is a non-issue.
place #2) JfxUtils is a non-existing item, but based on the error, this is not it either.
**Place #3** the getResource(fxml) is returning the null because it either points to something that doesn't exist, thus returning null, and you can't open a stream on a null object.

this line: `at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.isCyclic(FXMLLoader.java:1868)` in the exception stands out to me, although I don't have time right this second to dive in and explore it. Something in my gut tells me the cause of some of the weirdness might be tied into it.

Comment: I think that the `openStream()` is legal, because the `load()` method has [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) overload.

Comment: The fxml variable is a String

Comment: I don't understand, loader is not null and the return of getResource is not null too. I don't have access to isCyclic source, it's hard to debug

Comment: Ok I have a trail. This exception happens only when I have some fx:include tag in my fxml. But why ?

Comment: I think maybe you're making a circular dependency somewhere. I don't have any fx:include tags in my project being used, can you post up a small sample fxml that has the tag that seems to be breaking it in your OP? :)