# NullPointerException fx:include

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

When I do an fx:include in my fxml file, I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.equals(FXMLLoader.java:1856)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.isCyclic(FXMLLoader.java:1868)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2100(FXMLLoader.java:71)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:570)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2356)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2172)
```

Here is my root file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" fx:id="scrollPane" id="scrollStocksList"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="net.StocksListRunningController">
    <fx:include fx:id="tableListStock"
        source="/fxml/stocksList.fxml" />
</fx:root>
```

And my include file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="net.StockListTableController">
    <TableView fx:id="stocksList" onMouseClicked="#openDetail">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="Titre" prefWidth="125">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="title" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</fx:root>
```

If I remove my fx:include in my root file, all work fine.

I use the lastest version of java fx provided by jdk 7.0.51.

What is wrong in my include file (or other) ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException load fxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937057/nullpointerexception-load-fxml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Add this line for the loader:

```
loader.setLocation(JfxUtils.class.getResource(fxml));
```

Very bad bug.