# Gluon mobile view crash on Android

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile

i'm developing an app with [Gluon Mobile](https://gluonhq.com/). Recently i created a new view with presenter, added it to AppViewManager.class, and everything working on windows (when i use "run" gradle build script). But when i run an app on my Android phone (Oppo, Android 8.1) it's crash after switch to new view triggered from another view:

```
private void showDomainInfo(TaskDomainModel task) {
    System.out.println("CYBER_ESSENTIALS | going to start DOMAIN_VIEW...");
    getApp().LastDomainModel = task;
    AppViewManager.DOMAIN_VIEW.switchView();
}
```

App just crash without any helpfull information in the logcat:

```
12-12 16:12:43.537  1528  1528 E FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 2.0, touchXs0 = 348
12-12 16:12:43.609  1528  1561 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
12-12 16:12:43.609  1528  1561 I GLASS   : Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
12-12 16:12:43.609  1528  1561 I System.out: don't add points, primary = -1
12-12 16:12:43.641  1528  1561 I System.out: CYBER_ESSENTIALS | going to start DOMAIN_VIEW...
12-12 16:12:43.660  2063  4143 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.CyberEssentials/javafxports.android.FXActivity
12-12 16:12:43.669  1528  1528 V FXActivity: onPause
12-12 16:12:43.671  2063  2130 V WindowManager: reevaluateVisibility focusApp:AppWindowToken{12a47ed token=Token{4dcd53c ActivityRecord{fb1db2f u0 com.CyberEssentials/javafxports.android.FXActivity t4771}}}
12-12 16:12:43.682  2063  4887 D ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: The activity in ApplicationInfo{cadb841 com.oppo.launcher} is now in focus and seems to be in full-screen mode
12-12 16:12:43.682  2063  4887 E ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.oppo.launcher/com.oppo.launcher.Launcher/3
12-12 16:12:43.687  2063  4887 V WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{7cffb2b u0 com.CyberEssentials/javafxports.android.FXActivity} to null
12-12 16:12:43.690  2063  4887 D ActivityManager: zjm TOP_APP is ProcessRecord{345b1a2 22728:com.oppo.launcher/u0a20} uid is 10020
12-12 16:12:43.701  2063  2130 V WindowManager: reevaluateVisibility focusApp:AppWindowToken{4a759ed token=Token{a1e0328 ActivityRecord{f1c9d4b u0 com.oppo.launcher/.Launcher t4240}}}
12-12 16:12:43.708  1528  1561 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1528 SIG: 9
```

Here is my Presenter class for this problem view:

```
package com.CyberEssentials.views;

import com.CyberEssentials.CEApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.afterburner.GluonPresenter;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.BounceInRightTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class DomainDetailsPresenter extends GluonPresenter<CEApplication> {

    @FXML
    public Label domainInfoText;
    @FXML
    public TextField cmsDetails;
    @FXML
    public TextField categoryDetails;
    @FXML
    public TextField sslDetails;
    @FXML
    public CardPane subdomainsCardPane;
    @FXML
    public TextArea nmapScanText;
    @FXML
    public TextArea whoisDetails;
    @FXML
    public CardPane dnsReplCardPane;
    @FXML
    private View domainDetails;

    public void initialize() {
        domainDetails.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInRightTransition::new);

        domainDetails.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = getApp().getAppBar();
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_BACK.button(e ->
                        AppViewManager.DASHBOARD_VIEW.switchView()
                ));
                appBar.setTitleText(getApp().LastDomainModel.getDomain());
                appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SHARE.button(e ->
                        System.out.println("Share")));
                initVars();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initVars() {
        domainInfoText.setText("Report for " + getApp().LastDomainModel.getCreated());

        String cms = getApp().LastDomainModel.getCms();
        if (cms.equalsIgnoreCase("")) cms = "Unrecognized / none";
        cmsDetails.setText(cms);

        categoryDetails.setText(getApp().LastDomainModel.getCategory());

        subdomainsCardPane.getItems().addAll(getApp().LastDomainModel.getSubdomains());

        nmapScanText.setText(getApp().LastDomainModel.getNmap());
        whoisDetails.setText(getApp().LastDomainModel.getWhois());
    }

}
```

And fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    Copyright (c) 2017, Gluon and/or its affiliates.
    All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.

    This file is available and licensed under the following license:

    Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
    modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
    are met:

   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
   - Neither the name of Oracle Corporation and Gluon nor the names of its
     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
     from this software without specific prior written permission.

  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
  A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
  OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
  SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
  THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
-->

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<View xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="domainDetails" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
      minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="335.0"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.0" fx:controller="com.CyberEssentials.views.DomainDetailsPresenter">
    <center>
        <CardPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <items>
                <Label fx:id="domainInfoText" alignment="CENTER" text="\\%s domain information" textAlignment="CENTER"
                       wrapText="true">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Basic info">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <children>
                                <TextField editable="false" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="26.0"
                                           prefWidth="313.0" promptText="A content management system (CMS) :"/>
                                <TextField fx:id="cmsDetails" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="26.0"
                                           prefWidth="308.0" text="WordPress 4.4.2"/>
                                <TextField editable="false" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="26.0"
                                           prefWidth="304.0" promptText="Categories:"/>
                                <TextField fx:id="categoryDetails" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="77.0" prefHeight="26.0"
                                           prefWidth="308.0" text="gambling,sports"/>
                                <TextField editable="false" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="103.0" prefHeight="26.0"
                                           prefWidth="304.0" promptText="SSL / TLS:"/>
                                <TextField fx:id="sslDetails" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="26.0"
                                           prefWidth="305.0" text="Under developement"/>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" expanded="false" text="Subdomains">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="202.0" prefWidth="291.0">
                            <children>
                                <CardPane fx:id="subdomainsCardPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
                                          minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="203.0"
                                          prefWidth="317.0">
                                    <items>
                                    </items>
                                </CardPane>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" expanded="false" text="NMAP scan">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <children>
                                <TextArea fx:id="nmapScanText" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="177.0" prefWidth="316.0"
                                          promptText="Gluon Mobile is priced per developer with no royalties or hidden fees. Regardless of which tier you use (including the free tier), you will have everything you need to build great looking Android and iOS applications that are ready (and able) to be deployed into the appropriate app stores."/>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" expanded="false" text="Whois Lookup">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <children>
                                <TextArea fx:id="whoisDetails" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="177.0" prefWidth="316.0"
                                          promptText="Gluon Mobile is priced per developer with no royalties or hidden fees. Regardless of which tier you use (including the free tier), you will have everything you need to build great looking Android and iOS applications that are ready (and able) to be deployed into the appropriate app stores."/>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" expanded="false" text="Passive DNS Replication">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <children>
                                <CardPane fx:id="dnsReplCardPane" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="318.0">
                                    <items>
                                    </items>
                                </CardPane>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TextArea editable="false" prefHeight="79.0" prefWidth="319.0"
                          promptText="All the data provided by third party services, such as www.virustotal.com, api.hackertarget.com, Avast.com, whatcms.org."
                          text="All the data provided by third party services, such as www.virustotal.com, api.hackertarget.com, Avast.com, whatcms.org."
                          wrapText="true"/>
            </items>
        </CardPane>
    </center>
</View>
```

IDK if that's some Android related problem, but it's really weird. 
Looking forward to your help.

Comment: I'd suggest you use Injection to access your `LastDomainModel`, in the first place (In your presenters you can do `@Inject private LastDomainModel model;`). Anyway, can you add `try { getApp().LastDomainModel = task; } catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`  and run it again? It should post an stacktrace that might help you debugging the issue.

Comment: @josé-pereda thanks for your support, i removed all the usage of <LastDomainModel model> from the presenters, now it's just an empty new presenter with FXML injected fields. It works as expected on Windows, but still crash on Android. I'm going to create one more test empty view and have a look if it's work, may be some FXML objects or font or whatever else cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the problem is solved. 
I covered the code with try/catch as @josé-pereda recommended

```
try {
    AppViewManager.DOMAIN_VIEW.switchView();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("CYBER_ESSENTIALS | " + e);
}
```

And got an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load com/CyberEssentials/views/domaindetails.fxml
```

That helped me to find this answer [NullPointerException load fxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937057/nullpointerexception-load-fxml)

It didn't solved my problem, but i started to play around my fxml file name and it's variable name. It looks like fxml loader don't really like camel case in the file names.

New view is working now.

Comment: Good that you find a way to solve it. Indeed, Afterburner (not the FXMLLoader) requires all FXML, CSS and properties files lower cased.

Comment: @José Pereda I see, got confused cus it was working on Windows.